# How do I extract an old (iPad 2) app I developed from a mobile device back to source files

Tags: xcode, ipad, unity-game-engine, mobile, extract

I built a game back in 2012 that was in the apple store for about a year and never renewed my dev subscription so it was taken down. I found, what is likely, the only existing iPad that has the game still installed. I was hoping to extract the files and begin working on the game again in Unity.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively asking if it's possible to decompile an app back into source for Unity? No, that's impossible (or very hard). Without your existing xcode project, it's just not going to happen.

However, it looks like you could possibly get assets back via third party Unity Unpackers but I'm not sure on the validity of these tools as it's not officially supported.